# How to send sms to mobile using spring integration smpp library in java?

Tags: spring-integration, jsmpp

I am trying to send sms to mobile with smppsessionfactorybean. I configured host, port,systemid,password,bindtype,autostartup.(with nexmo sms server configuration).
But at the time of send() method call it is throwing

```
"java.io.IOException: Cannot submitShortMessage while in state CLOSED".
```

what is the meaning of this error?

sysout:-- SessionState: CLOSED

sysout:-- SessionId: 09ca74d9

IO error occur
java.io.IOException: Cannot submitShortMessage while in state CLOSED
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.ensureTransmittable(AbstractSession.java:375)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.ensureTransmittable(AbstractSession.java:358)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.submitShortMessage(SMPPSession.java:312)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9f8cc1d0.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:629)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$636b51bb.submitShortMessage()
    at org.springframework.integration.smpp.core.SmesMessageSpecification.send(SmesMessageSpecification.java:420)

Comment: Share, please, more StackTrace

Answer (score 1):

At the time of send, the smpp session is already closed and needs a binding again. so just before send check for the session is in the bind state, if not do connectAndBind() and send;